# Can I create a Album on my friend's account from selected photos of my Album on facebook?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I have created an Album and uploaded pics, I have also added details like description, date, where was it taken etc.. to individual photos.

Out of all pics in this album, I want to create a new Album on my friend's profile with only selected pics, without uploading again and adding same description, date etc..

Friend can choose his own visibility setting for this album for his friends.

Is there a direct way or we need graph API to do this?

Comment: You can not do that in a direct way or using the API

Comment: I think it should be possible using Graph API. Permissions shouldn't be an issue for me as me and my friend both agree on this.

Comment: @akjain No, that's not possible, see my answer

Answer (score 0):

As the `friend_*` permissions have been removed, this is no longer possible, and only would have if the friend granted an app the permission to do so.

See

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_0_permissions